# Git checkout transfers files to another branch

Tags: git

I was currently working on the master branch, I made some changes, stashed changes, and then checkout to the new branch when I type:

```
git status
```

it appeared that git transferred files that I used in the master branch. my question is: why did it do that? is it normal? and can you explain what happened here?

edit: I was on the master branch, I created file dato.py, I stashed that changes and I typed `git checkout feature_branch`, after that, I typed `git status`, and it appeared that dato.py file was on feature_branch too

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transferred"?

Comment: That sounds like exactly what a stash should do?

Comment: `git status` do not checkout a branch, it show the status of files regarding your current branch. What makes you think that git “transferred” some files at some point? Why did you stashed your changes as a first place? Please, give more context to you question so we can help you better.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I created new file dato.py and this file wasn't on feature branch. i stashed changes, and then i typed : git checkout. and then i typed git status, and it appeared that dato.py file was on feature branch too.

Comment: I edited, the question

Comment: Was `dato.py` being tracked? Did it actually get stashed (i.e. did you see a clean working state *before* switching branches)? If not, git is behaving as expected - unless there are conflicts, you can switch branches with a dirty working state and those changes will stay in the working state.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think it wasn't tracked, and why it happened, i don't understand, sorry i am new to git, still learning

Comment: When you check out a different branch, git will keep new files in your working folder as long as they don't conflict with the files that the "different branch" wants to place there. The main question here is whether you actually stashed the files (and thus they should've been removed from your working folder) or if something went wrong with the stash command. Assuming you didn't stash, it is entirely normal that new files are kept when you switch branches. Again, if there is no conflict with files in the target branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout feature_branch` will try to change your current branch to the `feature_branch` and by that it will sync your local directory (called working directory) to the files/directory in that branch.

If `dato.py` was there then, it means someone has already created/pushed that file on that branch.

But `git checkout` will no transfer any files, only `git fetch` (or `git pull`) will.

Regarding Johnsharpe comment, you may have thought you have stashed the `dato.py` file, but if it’s not tracked by git (was never added to the index, nor committed), the `stash` would have no effect on this file, and so, even after having changing your branch, the file will still be there.

That’s called *untracked files*, and so… there are actually untracked ;-)

Here an example with `stash`:

```sh
git init                                                                                                 100%  
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/cyrille/Documents/Projects/test/.git/
❯ echo toto > toto
❯ echo tata > tata
❯ ls
total 8,0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 tata
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 toto
❯ git add toto
❯ git commit -m "a file"
[master (root-commit) 5db6b8d] a file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 toto
❯ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    tata

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
❯ echo titi > titi
❯ ls
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 tata
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:44 titi
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 toto
❯ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    tata
    titi

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
❯ git add titi
❯ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   titi

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    tata

❯ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5db6b8d a file
❯ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    tata

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
❯ ls
total 8,0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 tata
-rw-r--r-- 1 cyrille cyrille 5  9 nov.   12:43 toto
```

`titi` file was stashed because I added it to the index (it’s now tracked) while `tata` file wasn’t and so stash command didn’t do anything with it.